# VB.NET WinForm Web Connection stopped working when project was upgraded from .NET 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, vb.net-2010, webclient, system.net.webexception

I've got a strange issue that's left me scouring Google for the past couple of hours, but I haven't found anything even close to this.

I have a VB.NET Winforms project containing a class that dynamically generates an image URL for a remotely hosted charting API, and returns the URL as the source to a PictureBox (`pbCallChart.ImageLocation = MyURL`). This has been in place and working fine for years now. However, I recently had to upgrade the project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 (I'm working in VS 2010 on a 64-bit build, which apparently won't let you do active debug in .NET 3.5). As soon as I did this, my image stopped showing up.

I verified that the image works when I pull up the URL in a web browser on the same machine that I'm working from. At first I figured maybe that property was removed in 4.0, so I tried switching to the Load() function. No dice. Then I took it one step further and wrote this little function:

```
Public Function ChartImage() As Bitmap
        Dim ChartURL As String = "http://www.anyURL.com/img.jpg" 'Chart()
        Return New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(ChartURL)))
End Function
```

When I run this (and I've confirmed that it doesn't matter what URL I pass it), I always get the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I know this isn't a proxy problem, because it works fine on this same computer under .NET 3.5. And I've confirmed it's not just a debugging quirk, because I compiled executables and provided them to users - they confirmed that the .NET 3.5 version works and the .NET 4.0 version does not.

I can only assume that there must be some security configuration difference in the two versions that I don't know about, but it seems like *someone* would have mentioned it somewhere. Has anyone else ever experienced anything like this? I'm pretty much out of ideas - do you have any?

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler? What's the stack trace? Is there an InnerException?

Comment: No InnerException, and the stack trace shows pretty much exactly what I'd expect - my main form calls calls the test function I wrote, and throws the exception when it tries to make the DownloadData call. Fiddler is an excellent option, which I'd never used before, but thank you for recommending. However, it seems to show that it's reaching out to get the image... here's a quick cut/paste:

Comment: Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      98  (headers:98; body:0)
Bytes Received:  640  (headers:128; body:512)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
ClientConnected:23:32:45.158
ClientBeginRequest:23:32:45.158
GotRequestHeaders:23:32:45.158
ClientDoneRequest:23:32:45.158
Determine Gateway:0ms
DNS Lookup:0ms
TCP/IP Connect:1000ms
HTTPS Handshake:0ms
ServerConnected:23:32:46.159
ClientBeginResponse:23:32:46.161
ClientDoneResponse:23:32:46.161

 Overall Elapsed: 00:00:01.0029682

RESPONSE BYTES
--------------
text/html: 512
~headers~: 128

Comment: Interestingly, though, when I turn Fiddler on, the exception I'm getting in Visual Studio changes slightly. It now reads: `The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.`